# How to calculate percentage figure from local database

Tags: c#, sql

I am currently trying to work out the percent remaining within a budget. The application I created is a budgeting application. The two columns I will be using to work out the calculation is BudgetAmount (this is the current balance of budget) and TransactionAmount (this is used to input expenses and income into the budget). I am unsure how to save the results from the sql query to a decimal value so I can work out percentage. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

(TransactionType = 2) - This means this type of transaction was an expense

This is the two sql statements for obtaining the data I think?

```
SqlCommand percentage = new SqlCommand("select * from UserBudget where budgetID=@budgetid", conn);

SqlCommand percentage2 = new SqlCommand("select * from userbudgettransaction where budgetID=@budgetid AND TransactionType = 2", conn);
```

Below is the database columns I am using:

UserBudget
[UserBudget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1L6V.png)
[UserBudgetTransaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDDZc.png)

Comment: Your SQL queries could be improved - 1) just select the BudgetAmount from the budget and 2) select the SUM(TransactionAmount) from the transactions. Then you can use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idbcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get the values, cast them as decimals, and then work out the percentage. You could also use just one SQL command to get both values, then use [`ExecuteReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idbcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.7.2) to read the result ...

Comment: ... `SELECT BudgetAmount, SUM(TransactionAmount) as SumTransactions FROM UserBudget JOIN UserBudgetTransaction ON UserBudget.BudgetId = UserBudgetTransaction.BudgetId WHERE UserBudget.BudgetId = @budgetId`

Comment: SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnect"].ConnectionString);
            // Create the SelectCommand.
            SqlCommand percentage = new SqlCommand("SELECT BudgetAmount, SUM(TransactionAmount) as SumTransactions FROM UserBudget JOIN UserBudgetTransaction ON UserBudget.BudgetId = UserBudgetTransaction.BudgetId WHERE UserBudget.BudgetId = @budgetId AND TransactionType = 2", conn);
            percentage.Parameters.AddWithValue("@budgetid", Session["budgetId"].ToString());
            Decimal Percent = (Decimal)percentage.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: This is my code so far, I am unsure how select the exact columns to then use to calculate the percentage.

Comment: If you use this instead - `SELECT SUM(TransactionAmount) / BudgetAmount as Percentage FROM …` - then that returns one value, which can then retrieve with ExecuteScalar.

Comment: I am getting following error message - 'Invalid column name 'Percentage'.'

Comment: SqlCommand percentage = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(TransactionAmount) / BudgetAmount as Percentage FROM UserBudget JOIN UserBudgetTransaction ON UserBudget.BudgetId = UserBudgetTransaction.BudgetId WHERE UserBudget.BudgetId = @budgetId AND TransactionType = 2 group by Percentage", conn);

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply, I still seem to be getting an error saying: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Column 'UserBudget.BudgetAmount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

Comment: Hi stuartd thank you for quick reply, it seems I am still getting same error message at the ExecuteScalar part.

Comment: What's your exact SQL statement?

Comment: I am using the same SQL statement you provided me with: SELECT SUM(TransactionAmount) / BudgetAmount as Percentage FROM UserBudget JOIN UserBudgetTransaction ON UserBudget.BudgetID = UserBudgetTransaction.BudgetID WHERE UserBudget.BudgetID = @budgetid AND TransactionType = 2 group by UserBudget.BudgetID

Comment: `group by UserBudget.BudgetID, BudgetAmount`

Comment: Hi it seems to be printing out result: 1.000000 which isnt correct at all, however thank you for your quick respones, apologies for taking up your time.

Comment: What datatypes are TransactionAmount and BudgetAmount ? (It would help if you edited your question to include your table structures, some sample data, and the result you expect to get)

Comment: TransactionAmount = decimal(18,2) BudgetAmount = varchar(50) updated images for sample data has been included

Comment: .. BudgetAmount is a **varchar**? Is that right?

Comment: Yes correct, however I tired changing it to decimal aswell, which didnt work.

Comment: OK, I've added some working code as an answer. Note that you really should store the budget amount as some kind of numeric datatype rather than varchar(50).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with some sample data: note I have multiplied the division by 100 to get the actual percentage.

```sql
 create table UserBudget (BudgetId int, BudgetAmount varchar(50))
 create table UserBudgetTransaction (UserBudgetTransactionId int, BudgetId int, TransactionAmount decimal(18, 2), TransactionType int)
 insert into UserBudget (BudgetId, BudgetAmount) values (1, '100000')
 insert into UserBudget (BudgetId, BudgetAmount) values (2, '200000')

 insert into UserBudgetTransaction (UserBudgetTransactionId, BudgetId, TransactionAmount, TransactionType ) values (3, 1, '1000', 1)
 insert into UserBudgetTransaction (UserBudgetTransactionId, BudgetId, TransactionAmount, TransactionType ) values (4, 1, '20000', 2)
 insert into UserBudgetTransaction (UserBudgetTransactionId, BudgetId, TransactionAmount, TransactionType) values (5, 1, '50000', 2)

 declare @budgetId int = 1

 select * from UserBudget
 select * from UserBudgetTransaction

 SELECT (SUM(TransactionAmount) / BudgetAmount) * 100 as Percentage 
 FROM UserBudget JOIN UserBudgetTransaction ON UserBudget.BudgetID = UserBudgetTransaction.BudgetID 
 WHERE UserBudget.BudgetID = @budgetid AND TransactionType = 2 
 group by UserBudget.BudgetID, BudgetAmount
```

This returns these values:

[image]

And in code:

```cs
var sql = @"SELECT (SUM(TransactionAmount) / BudgetAmount) * 100 as Percentage 
 FROM UserBudget JOIN UserBudgetTransaction ON UserBudget.BudgetID = UserBudgetTransaction.BudgetID
 WHERE UserBudget.BudgetID = @budgetid AND TransactionType = 2
 group by UserBudget.BudgetID, BudgetAmount";

 decimal result;

 using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Budgets;Trusted_Connection=True"))
 {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        var parameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("budgetId", SqlDbType.Int);
        parameter.Value = 1;
        conn.Open();

        result = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();      
    }
 }

 Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Which returns:

[image]

Comment: Hi, it seems only value '100.000000' is appearing no matter what transaction I input.

Comment: Sorry, this is the best I can do with the information you've given. If you need more help you're going to have to give more detail - sample data and code which shows the problem you're having in a reproducible fashion. And please don't post images, edit your question with actual data and your code.